# Meaning of pk_set on m2m_changed

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-signals

Django docs states:

```
pk_set
For the pre_add, post_add, pre_remove and post_remove actions, this is a set of primary key values that have been added to or removed from the relation.
For the pre_clear and post_clear actions, this is None.
```

The difference between the relation after being modified and the current state of the relation was exactly what I needed.

But when trying to use that on django admin I get the whole relation. I think if I wanted it all I would just use the `instance` parameter.

This looks like it's because clear is being called when I submit the form. So, it's basically wiping out every model and adding again(since keeping track of the model added/remove is a bit annoying). But that way this feature has no significance.

I want to listen for modifications on  a manytomany relation and get only the ones that were added. And I'd like to do that on django admin.

If you provide a way to do that, please, also tell me how could that be done using `through`

Thanks!